# Focus html page or element from a webview with talckback

Tags: android, android-webview, accessibility

I have an hybrid app developed with ionic 1.x. When the app loads I am forcing the webview to take the focus from native side with the hope that after some initialization request a survey dialog appear and take the focus it self(When dialog appear I am forcing it to take focus). I am trying to make it work with talkback

The problem is that when you load the app from scratch the dialog is not focused so it is not read, after navigate through the app and come back to the original page then in works as expected, looks like as the user is in fact inside the page things works ok.

Is there any workaround or strategy to solve this particular situation?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it helps you,
but we use it to focus on specific elements in the web view.
it works in android and ios,
**but in android, before every element it read webview.
(if you found a solution for it please let me know)**

```
   function putFocus(elementForFocus) {
        var $element = $(elementForFocus);
        var focusInterval = 10; // ms, time between function calls
        var focusTotalRepetitions = 10; // number of repetitions

        $element.attr('tabindex', '0');
        $element.blur();

        var focusRepetitions = 0;
        var interval = window.setTimeout(function () {
            $element.focus();
        }, focusInterval);
    };
```